# Call external Solidity contract with interface and delegateCall

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

normally I call external contracts by importing an interface of the external contract and generating a "local variable" of the contract, once I need it. Something like this:

```
import "./CalleeInterface";

contract Caller {

  function callExternalFunction(address _calleeAddr){
    CalleeInternface callee = CalleeInterface(_calleeAddr);
    callee.someExternalFunction();
}
```

My problem is, that above way seems to use function `call` implicitly. 
Now I am facing a situation, where the external function checks the address of the sender. When I use above way, `msg.sender` is the address of contract `Caller`. Since I want to "forward" the address of the actual caller, I need to call the external function using `delegatecall`:

```
contract Caller {
  function callExternalFunction(address _calleeAddr){
    _calleeAddr.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("someExternalFunction()")));
}
```

As you can see, the interface is not required in this situation, but the code is a bit more complex.
Now my question is, if there is a way to use `delegatecall` with the "interface way" of calling external function?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to my problem:
Sadly, one cannot receive values from `delegatecall` function calls.

Comment: For the record: When using `delegatecall`, you have to use the exact data type specification within the function string (`uint256` instead of just `uint`). You also do not need to specify the parameter names. So a function with header `function doSomething(uint _num) public` should be called like this `delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("doSomething(uint256)")),_myVar)`.

Comment: If by "receive values" you mean get a return value from a function you delegate called - you can. All you have to do is abi.decode()